# Add overlay color to an image using Xamarin.Forms

Tags: image, xamarin.forms

I'd like to add some icons in my app especially in listviews using custom cell and specify the color to be rendered.
I don't want to edit each image in Photoshop; I want to apply an overlay color at runtime.

Is that possible with a custom renderer?

Comment: Why don't you put a `Grid` or something similar on top which you give a `BackgroundColor` and a `Opacity`?

Comment: What have you tried? See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No it is not possible through standard `Image` class provided in Xamarin.Forms.

But you can use this amazing `IconView` custom renderer created by this guy. I use it all the time it is amazing.

[IconView for Xamarin Forms](https://github.com/andreinitescu/IconApp)

**Usage**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="IconApp.MyPage"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:IconApp;assembly=IconApp">
  <controls:IconView Source="monkey"
                     Foreground="Red"
                     WidthRequest="100"
                     HeightRequest="100"
                     HorizontalOptions="Center"
                     VerticalOptions="Center" />
</ContentPage>
```

Just specify the `Foreground="Red"` property color

[image]

Comment: Super Awesome. Thanks Man :)

Comment: it working perfectly on images. is it possible to make it work on an image button?

Answer (score 2):

Now We got another way with **Xamarin.CommunityToolkit**. We can use its `IconTintColorEffect.TintColor` for changing Tint Color or Overlay of an Image.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"
         x:Class="MyLittleApp.MainPage">
    <StackLayout>
        <Image Source="monkey" xct:IconTintColorEffect.TintColor="Red" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

**Xamarin.CommunityToolkit** is handy and provides lot of features such as Shadows on any View, `EventToCommandBehavior` for MVVMifying lot of Events and Controls, it also has additional Converters, Extensions, Helpers, and Views that are not available in builtin Xamarin Forms yet.

[Refer for more Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/)