# Iconize with Xamarin Forms (on Android)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I have not been able to get Iconize to work at all. I created a small test project based on the code in this thread (among other places):

[How to change icon color in Xamarin.Forms xaml page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38020048/how-to-change-icon-color-in-xamarin-forms-xaml-page)

In App.xaml.cs:

```cs
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Plugin.Iconize.Iconize.With(new Plugin.Iconize.Fonts.MaterialDesignIconsModule());
    MainPage = new MainPage();
}
```

In MainActivity.cs:

```cs
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
    ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

    Plugin.Iconize.Iconize.Init(Resource.Id.toolbar, Resource.Id.sliding_tabs);

    LoadApplication(new App());
}
```

and MainPage.xaml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:IconizeTest"
             xmlns:iconize="clr-namespace:Plugin.Iconize;assembly=Plugin.Iconize"
             x:Class="IconizeTest.MainPage">
    <StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <iconize:IconImage HeightRequest="20" Icon="mdi-bus-double-decker" IconColor="Blue" WidthRequest="20" />
            <iconize:IconImage HeightRequest="20" Icon="mdi-bus-double-decker" BackgroundColor="Blue" IconColor="Yellow" WidthRequest="20" IconSize="10" />
            <iconize:IconButton FontSize="20" Text="mdi-bus-double-decker" TextColor="Red" WidthRequest="48" />
            <iconize:IconLabel FontSize="20" Text="mdi-bus-double-decker" TextColor="Green" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
            <Label Text="mdi-bus-double-decker" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Here's a picture of what the output looks like in an emulator (looks the same on my test device...):

[image]

I like the idea of using iconize, it will tremendously reduce the amount of time I take dorking with icons. I just can't get it to work. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!
-Karen

Comment: Don't you get any error whatsoever?

Comment: @BrunoCaceiro Nope. Just re-ran and checked. No error messages in the Application Output window.

Answer (score 0):

Font icons can be used directly in `Label`.

`Image` and `ImageButton` supports defining [font icons](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/fonts#display-font-icons) in `FontImageSource`, see example using [Iconize](https://github.com/jsmarcus/Iconize) [Material Design Icons](https://github.com/jsmarcus/Iconize/blob/master/samples/Iconize.Sample.WPF/iconize-materialdesignicons.ttf) below:

```
<ContentPage ...
             xmlns:fonts="clr-namespace:Fonts" 
             ...
             >
<ContentPage.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <OnPlatform x:Key="MaterialDesignIcons" x:TypeArguments="x:String">
        <On Platform="iOS" Value="Material Design Icons" />
        <On Platform="Android" Value="iconize-materialdesignicons.ttf#Material Design Icons" />
        <On Platform="UWP" Value="Assets/Fonts/iconize-materialdesignicons.ttf#Material Design Icons" />
    </OnPlatform>
  </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
...
<Image BackgroundColor="LightGray">
    <Image.Source>
        <FontImageSource Glyph="{x:Static fonts:MaterialDesign.access_point}"
                         FontFamily="{StaticResource MaterialDesignIcons}" 
                         Color="Blue" Size="10" />
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
<ImageButton BackgroundColor="LightGray">
    <ImageButton.Source>
        <FontImageSource Glyph="{x:Static fonts:MaterialDesign.bus_double_decker}"
                         FontFamily="{StaticResource MaterialDesignIcons}" 
                         Color="Red" Size="20" />
    </ImageButton.Source>
</ImageButton>
<Label Text="{x:Static fonts:MaterialDesign.lock}" 
       FontFamily="{StaticResource MaterialDesignIcons}" 
       TextColor="Green" FontSize="20" BackgroundColor="LightGray" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
```

The font icons can be defined as follows, example from [Iconize](https://github.com/jsmarcus/Iconize) fonts in [`Iconize/src/Fonts/Plugin.Iconize.MaterialDesignIcons/MaterialDesignIconsCollection.cs`](https://github.com/jsmarcus/Iconize/blob/master/src/Fonts/Plugin.Iconize.MaterialDesignIcons/MaterialDesignIconsCollection.cs);

```
Icons.Add("mdi-access-point", '\uf002');
...
Icons.Add("mdi-bus-double-decker", '\uf79d');
...
Icons.Add("mdi-lock", '\uf33e');
...
```

So the class `MaterialDesign` below is placed in the same assembly as the `ContentPage` would be:

```
namespace Fonts
{
    public static class MaterialDesign
    {
#pragma warning disable IDE1006 // Naming Styles
        public static string access_point => "\uf002";
        ...
        public static string bus_double_decker => "\uf79d";
        ...
        //lock is a keyword in c#, so add "@" to use it as name of property
        public static string @lock => "\uf33e";
        ...
#pragma warning restore IDE1006 // Naming Styles
    }
}
```

The key,value entries of the Iconize `MaterialDesignIconsCollection` class can be converted to the auto property syntax of the `MaterialDesign` class using e.g. search/replace in a text editor (not shown here).

In this example the [`iconize-materialdesignicons.ttf`](https://github.com/jsmarcus/Iconize/blob/master/samples/Iconize.Sample.WPF/iconize-materialdesignicons.ttf) font file is placed in the `Assets` folder on Android (build action `AndroidAsset`), `Resources` folder on iOS (build action `BundleResource`), and `Assets/Fonts` on UWP (build action `Content`).

On iOS add the font to `Info.plist` in the `<app>.iOS` project:

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
<array>
    <string>iconize-materialdesignicons.ttf</string>
</array>
```

Comment: If I'm putting the .ttf file in assets, and not using Iconize* controls, then it's not really using Iconize, is it? (Read that with no snark, just an honest question. It's just lil ole me here trying to figure out stuff from google search results...)

I was going to try this approach if I didn't get Iconize sorted out, and your instructions will be a huge help. One more question... How do you figure out the character code for the icon you want? One of the advantages of Iconize is that I could use the names, I found an easy resource to figure them out...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You would be using the font file from Iconize and code points, i.e. the names and character codes. See edit.