# ToolbarItem IconImageSource original colors on Android

Tags: xamarin.forms

ToolbarItem image is using mono color instead of its original colors.

Here is my code:

```
 <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
     <ToolbarItem IconImageSource="logo.png"
              Order="Primary"
              Priority="0">
     </ToolbarItem>
 </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

I am trying to add a logo in the center of the toolbar using its original colors. Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: You can use the the [Iconize Plugin](https://github.com/jsmarcus/Iconize) according to the [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38020048/how-to-change-icon-color-in-xamarin-forms-xaml-page). In addition, you can use the custom renderer like this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/516401/xamarin-forms-change-toolbaritem-icon-color-on-and.html).

Comment: what finally worked for me without using a plugin is to simply put the image inside "Shell.TitleView" tag. the image is now colorful.
hope this will help others. thanks anyway!