# How change the color of image on click in Xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a white heart I have to change it to an orange heart on click. This is the screenshot of the UI I need

[image: https://us.v-cdn.net/5019960/uploads/editor/lv/a3u7ftuy02rb.png]

As you can see in the screenshot. I know I have to add one white heart icon initially then once I click on it the orange heart icon should be displayed. This is my code.

```
<Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="5" Margin="0,10,0,0" Source="whitehearticon3"/>
```

But I'm not getting any example regarding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to my old answer here [Add overlay color to an image using Xamarin.Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37860955/add-overlay-color-to-an-image-using-xamarin-forms/37861038#37861038) **on how to add an overlay color on every image**.

Then it is easy to add a `TapGestureRecognizer` command and change the color like this

```
<customControls:IconView
    Source="monkey"
    Foreground="{Binding myColor}"
    WidthRequest="100"
    HeightRequest="100"
    HorizontalOptions="Center"
    VerticalOptions="Center" >
    <customControls:IconView.GestureRecognizers>
         <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding ChangeColorCommand}"/>
    </customControls:IconView.GestureRecognizers>
</customControls:IconView>
```

Create a a `Color myColor` property on your viewmodel and change it through your command

```
public ICommand ChangeColorCommand { get; private set; }
public Color MyColor
{
    get => _myColor;
    set
    {
        _myColor = value; 
        RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}

void ChangeColor()
{
    MyColor = Color.Red;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use

`<ImageButton Source="whitehearticon3.png" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="5" Margin="0,10,0,0" />`

Add 2 heart icons to your resource folders, one normal and one orange.
Then all you have to do is to raise a clicked event or command and change the source of the ImageButton to the orange icon.

Answer (score -1):

To achieve this:

You need two images in your resource folder. whitehearticon3.png & pinkhearticon3.png

There should be one Boolean property which changes when we tap on Heart icon.

```
private bool _isLiked;
public bool IsLiked
{
    get { return _isLiked; }
    set
    {
        _isLiked = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("IsLiked");
    }
}
```

Now you can use the `DataTrigger` on Image to change the image source based on the value of this property.

```
<Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="5" Margin="0,10,0,0">
    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding HeartTapCommand}" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
    <Image.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger TargetType="Image" Binding="{Binding IsLiked}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Source" Value="pinkhearticon3.png"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger TargetType="Image" Binding="{Binding IsLiked}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Source" Value="whitehearticon3.png"/>
        </DataTrigger>
     </Image.Triggers>
</Image>
```

In your ViewModel you would be having the `HeartTapCommand` as follows:

```
ICommand HeartTapCommand { get; set; } = new Command (() => { IsLiked = !IsLiked; });
```

You should bind this command on Image `TapGuesture`, so when you tap on image, this command will get executed and you can switch between your two Heart icons.